# Slim router url calls controller without hardcoding the map

Tags: php, slim

I am generating a SLIM error I don't understand:  Missing argument 1 for {closure}()

What I am trying to do is automatically map a controller pulled out of the url to the controller file, without hardcoding the filename. It works fine if I go to somesite.com/accounting, however when I comment out the hardcode route to accounting it does not work, error Missing argument 1 for {closure}().

```
$url = str_replace( WEB_PATH, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$split_url = explode('/', $url);
$controller_name = $split_url[1];


$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/', function () 
{
   echo 'home';
});
$app->get('/accounting',  function () 
{
   $controller = new accounting;
});
$app->get('/purchaseOrders',  function () 
{
   $controller = new purchaseOrders;
});
//this should work but does not...
$app->get('/'. $controller_name,  function ($controller_name) 
{
  echo $controller_name;
   $controller = new $controller_name;
});
$app->get('test.php', function () 
{
   $controller = new test;
});
$app->run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using parameter in routes, you have to write your route path as follows:

```
$app->get('/:controller_name',  function ($controller_name) 
{
    echo $controller_name;
    $controller = new $controller_name;
});
```

All parameters are strings with a `:` prepended to it. You can use multiple parameters separated by slashes if you need.

Using the code above to declare your route, Slim will internally fill your `$controller_name` argument with the value in the parameter.

When accessing `/accounting`, the argument will hold the value `'accounting'`.

Refer to the [routing parameter documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/params/) on more details about how to use parameters with Slim routes.